# jade using javascript variable (mongo model)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, pug

I am using node.js to create website and trying to use data model created in js file.

Even after res.render() is called in the routes/browse.ts, the result from the iteration in the jade file wont show up as the result in the webpage created. It seems like there is something wrong with how I am iterating in each-in part of the jade fileAlthough console.log shows that my comicArray in browse.ts is not empty. 
here is my code you can refer to:

routes/browse.ts:

```
// Comic GET request
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
// Saving found comics into the array named 'comics'
comic.comicModel.find({}, function(err, comics){
    if (err || !comics) throw err;
    res.locals.comicArray = comics.slice(0, 10);
    comicArray = res.locals.comicArray;
  });
res.render('browse', { title: 'Browse', comicArray: comicArray});
});
```

views/browse.jade:

```
extends layout
block content
    .row.column.text-centent
        h1= title

    .listbox
        ul
            each val in comicArray
                li= val.title
```

models/Comic.ts (schema for Comic):

```
export var comicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    genre: String,    
    thumbnail: String,
    cells: Array,
    votes: Number,
    views: Number,
    comments: Array    
 });
```

Comment: OH i have not stated my question fully enough.

Comment: Even after res.render() is called in the routes/browse.ts, the result from the iteration in the jade file wont show up as the result in the webpage created. It seems like there is something wrong with how I am iterating in each-in part of the jade file.

Comment: Do not use the comments box for additional info. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35290999/edit) link on your question to include this.

Comment: You need to call res.render from inside find callback function otherwise the comicArray would still be undefined. The find function is async which means res.render is called before the result is returned from DB.

Comment: thank you all for help. I have revised my code as suggested, and it is working perfectly fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comic.comicModal.find()` is an asynchronous function. You need to move the `res.render()` call inside that callback.